# Part specific questions.

Tags: feature-request

I don't ask a lot of question's because they feel part specific.
Would there be some way to ask part specific questions?....
Like : "Has anyone else seen this big noise peak at X kHz in this opamp?"
And put a time limit on it so that if there was not enough interest, (up votes) it would go away in a year, or whatever.  But still there might be some helpful discussion.

Just asking.

Answer (score 5):

Go ahead and ask.  Those questions are on-topic, and we've got plenty of server space.